# Empty PHP Session Array after Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to create a login page and home page (HTML and javascript) on the client side and PHP files to check with the database and start session on the server side.

I have been testing the code with live server on visual studio code and my PHP code runs on XAMPP Apache server.

I have a login.js file that sends information to the server and then checks if login was successful:

```
window.onload = function onLoadFunction() {
    $("#login-form").on("submit", function (e) {
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        console.log("dataString: " + dataString);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/healthcareProvider/login.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if(res == "success"){
              window.location="http://localhost:5500/index.html";
            }else{
              console.log("login failure");
            }
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
}
```

my login.php file has the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// some code to connect to database

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            echo 'success';
} else { echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';} 
?>
```

This code works fine. When I do `var_dump($_SESSION)` I get an array with all the fields I set.

After the redirect to index.html, my index.js file checks if the session is set by sending an AJAX request to checksession.php file.

index.js code:

```
function checkSession(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/healthcareProvider/checksession.php",
        type: "GET",
        xhrFields:{
          withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (data) {
          if(data === "success"){
            console.log("success");
          }else{
            console.log("failure: ", data);
          }
        }
    });
}
```

my checksession.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5500');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    echo "failure";
}else{
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

my problem is that I get "failure" every time and when I check `var_dump($_SESSION)` I get an empty session array.

I have checked that the PHPSESSID cookie is sent and received and that session files are created in the tmp/ folder.

Any idea why I am not getting the session information I set in the login.php file and how I can fix it so I can get that information?

Sorry for the lengthy question, and thank you ever so much for any suggestion you might have!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental HTTP issue that even the most-cursory internet search would have found.

"Sessions" rely on the `set-cookie:` response from the **server,** which only occurs if you actually sent something to the server.

"Redirects" don't.  You're telling the **client** to go somewhere else.

Comment: First of all, I spent many hours searching for answers on the internet,  so I did more than a "cursory" internet search. As to the rest of your answer, I didn't just redirect, I sent a get request to the server, and the cookie is in the header. Maybe you didn't read the question...

Answer (score 0):

So, I have managed to solve my problem.

I don't know if this is a good explanation, but maybe it'll help someone who runs into a similar issue.

Basically, my login AJAX request was not sending a cookie with the header, and because I was testing logging in and redirecting with successful login without actually logging out/ending sessions, my PHP login file kept creating new sessions with new session id's. I was able to see that with `echo session_id();`

I added to my login.php file the following code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

and changed the AJAX in my login.js file to allow the cookie to be sent

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/healthcareProvider/login.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if(res == "success"){
              window.location="http://localhost:5500/index.html";
            }else{
              console.log("login failure");
            }
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
```

And that solved my problem.